# Disable Booking status update option in WCFM if booking is pending, Cancelled & unpaid

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I'm using Hook from wcfm to disable the status update option but it's not working. I want to restrict the vendors from updating status.

```
add_action( 'wcfm_booking_overview_block', 'disable_cancelled_booking', 20, 2 ); 
function disable_cancelled_booking($booking, $product) { 
global $current_user; //Get User Role 
$user_roles = $current_user->roles; 
$user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

//Checking Status of booking & role of the current user based on that the status update field will be hidden 
if(($booking->status == "cancelled" || $booking->status == "unpaid"|| $booking->status == "pending-confirmation") && $user_role =="wcfm_vendor") { 
//Disable option
 } }
```

Comment: Are you sure your hook is called? Have you logged out something in the hook to verify this?

Comment: The above hook is of booking page from here I will get the current booking object. I just want the status update option to be hidden or disabled

Comment: Have you ever thought a minute about my comment? Sometimes hooks are not called. I asked you if you verified if your hook gets called by logging out something.

Comment: yes it's getting called. I've printed $booking object within hook & it's working. print_r($booking);

Comment: add_filter( 'wcfm_is_allow_booking_status_update', false ); this inside if statement resolves the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a filter from wcfm 'wcfm_is_allow_booking_status_update'which does the trick

Comment: Thanks this works. I've added add_filter( 'wcfm_is_allow_booking_status_update', false ); & It hides the status bar